# How do I notationally write 6 and -6 are the only solutions of the equation $x^2=36$?

Tags: notation

I would like to notationally write ''$6$ and $-6$ are the only solutions of the equation $x^2=36$'' using double turnstiles.

Is it something like this?

$$⊨ x∈{-6,6} ↔ x^2=36$$

Comment: $\forall x\;(x=6\lor x=-6)\iff (x^2=36)$... or... $\forall x\;(x\in \{-6,6\}\iff x^2=36)$.  So $x$ is not a free variable, and you have a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these

$$\vDash \forall x\,(\,
|x|=6 \iff x^2=36)$$

$$\vDash\forall x\, (\,x\in \{6,-6\} \iff x^2=36)$$
are equivalent and correct (with basic assumptions as the domain being $\Bbb R$, etc).

Answer (score 0):

For example, it is used to write

$$x^2=36\implies |x|=6\iff x=\pm 6$$

Or more "logically":

$$x=\pm 6\vDash x^2=36\;,\;\;\text{or}\;\;\;\;|x|=6\vDash x^2=36$$

Comment: But I would like to use double turnstiles please :(

Comment: @SethKitchen I'm not sure, but look now.

Comment: @SethKitchen I don't see how the first statement doesn't say exactly what you need.  I wouldn't think for a second that $x$ could be anything other than $\pm 6$ the way it was written.  What extra does the double turnstiles buy you?

Comment: that says "x being 6 or -6 entails $x^2=36$", but does not state "x being 6 or -6 are the only elements which entail $x^2=36$"

Comment: @SethKitchen The first line **does** say *exactly* that. With the double turnstile I already am not that sure, though perhaps there's some symbol like $\;\exists\,!\;$ to denote "exists *unique* but  with turnstiles...but I'm not sure. You can, of course, add $\;\wedge\,|x|\neq6\implies x^2\neq36\;$ , for unicity.

Comment: @john I am writing basic algebra, and have already introduced the turnstile, but not absolute value. That will be a future chapter

Comment: You are introducing basic logic symbolism without assuming something as basic as absolute value?

Comment: @Joanpemo To take the first definition, you must know to take the square root of both sides and that the square root gives you the absolute value of x. But in the intro, we haven't talked about solving linear equations, so they won't know to use the square root and therefore not the absolute value. Idk maybe we should shift some things around

Comment: @SethKitchen Ok, anyway: you can dispose of the absolute value and use the double sign $\;\pm\;$ or something like that.

Comment: OP's turnstile expression is correct.